Why does incrementing a pointer to an array give this result?
If I define a new (int) array, and increment the dereferenced pointer to this array by 1, why do I get the following result?
int main()
{
    
    int myArray[1024];

    myArray[0] = 123;
    myArray[1] = 456;

    printf("%d \n", *myArray);
    printf("%d \n", *myArray+1);

    return 0;
}

The output is:
123 
124

Why is the next value not 456? And, why does the output skip over 3?

I have no idea what you mean by "why does the output skip over 3?" What 3?

You do not increment anything. Incrementing would mean you change the value of a variable which you do not. You only add 1 to some value without altering that value.

Operator precedence. The * binds more tightly, so the + 1 applies to the result of dereferencing. *(myArray + 1) would give you the result you expect, 456. As would the rather more idiomatic myArray[1].

Makes sense. OK. Thank you!
